# Link not working in LI

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, html-lists

OMG I'm pulling my hair out trying to figure out why some links don't work in the UL. However if your right click open in new tab that works. I don't understand why some are not clickable. The first two links work but they are events used by jQuery. 3rd and 4th links are actual pages and those don't work and never does the last javascript/jquery link. Just the first two using jQuery. The others do not. I've reformatted my CSS several times and no difference. The unusual tags is because I use Smarty. BTW using Chrome.

This is the HTML

**Edit: rendered markup**

```
<div id="phomenu" class="photoMenu">
    <ul>
    <li><a id="avatar_13885_10028" class="set_avatar" href="#13885">Use This Photo As Avatar</a></li>
    <li><a id="cover_13885_10028" class="set_cover" href="#13885">Use This Photo As Album Cover</a></li>
    <li><a href="/page-13885-k4cjGSDSG4K.html">Page Photo</a></li>
    <li><a href="/?page=photo&amp;section=desc&amp;pho_id=13885">Edit Photo Information</a></li>
    <li><a id="remove_k4cjGSDSG4K_13885" class="remove_photo" href="javascript:void(0)">Delete this photo</a></li>
    <li><a id="feature_13885" class="feature_photo" href="javascript:void(0)">Feature Photo</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And this is the CSS

```
.photoMenu ul{
        list-style-type: none;
        list-style-position: outside;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-size:9pt;
        border-top: 2px solid #ffa449;
    }
    .photoMenu li {
        margin: 0;
    }
    .photoMenu li a {
        color: #FFFFFF;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
        display:block;
        min-height:25px;
        padding-top:10px;
        background-color:#C6711B;
        text-decoration: none;

    }
    .photoMenu li a:hover {
        color: #FFF;
        background-color: #f2a83a;
    }
```

Comment: Show us the **generated** markup, please. The browser doesn't see smarty tags, so that's not going to help diagnose the issue.

Comment: Added the rendered markup.

Comment: The 3rd and 4th links look like they work to me, there's something else missing here:  http://jsfiddle.net/9XMVp/.  The last 2 links can't possibly work because they have `href="javascript:void(0)"`.

Comment: @cinnamon The two links are click events with Jquery. The 4th actually does work but not the 5th. Anyway, I removed everything from the page except just that code and still doesn't work. So weird. I can't see where I would have a conflict. ughhh

Comment: As I already said, the 5th and 6th links (the last 2) can't possibly work because of `href="javascript:void(0)"`.

Comment: @cimmanon yes they do as mentioned they are jQuery click events. I actually fixed my problem. Duplicate IDs. However I haven't changed my code and "last 2" work as they always have. I just moved them into a Unordered list and that's when I got the problem. Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you have shown so far does not have any problem. The problem is somewhere else, may be your script is interfering with the link.

<kbd>[Proof](http://jsfiddle.net/DZD25/)</kbd>

If the browser is just made at you, it can get angry with the `javascript:void(0)` part

Although unnecessary it may require a `;` at the last

```
<li><a id="remove_k4cjGSDSG4K_13885" class="remove_photo" href="javascript:void(0);">Delete this photo</a></li>
<li><a id="feature_13885" class="feature_photo" href="javascript:void(0);">Feature Photo</a></li>
```

Comment: I'll give you this one since you got me to thinking about a "script" JS conflict even though the first two links worked and the physical pages did not. Anyway, I removed the ID="phoMenu" from the div and that fixed it. I was conflicting with a jQuery event I set for something else with that same ID. I have a lot of functions. LOL Anyway, sometimes you just need a push into thinking outside the box. Thx.